# Assigning a value to how 'ordered' a vector is

Tags: statistics

Consider a vector which goes in ascending order from (1, 2, 3 ... N). This vector is ordered 'correctly' and I would like to assign it a score of 1, which indicates a perfectly ascending ordered vector.

On the other hand, a vector (N, N-1, N-2 ... 3, 2, 1) has the 'worst' possible score of 0.

In between 0 and 1, the vector can be 'scrambled' and I would like a way to calculate how 'ordered' it is compared to the perfect case of (1, 2, 3 ... N).

Does anyone know of a way to calculate such a score which measures the ordered-ness of a vector?

Comment: Pick your favorite sorting algorithm, and define the sortedness as the number of iterations required.

Comment: Or count the number consecutive values that are in ascending order $a$ and divide by $n-1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start off you could measure the [Inversion number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_(discrete_mathematics)) of the vector.

In many cases the 'sortedness' measure is used to understand how many operations are needed to sort the vector using a particular algorithm. In that case, the measure of disorder could depend on the method used for sorting. It could be:

- number of inversions
- number of swaps
- number of times a subsequence needs to be reversed
  etc

If you plan to use the sortedness measure to understand the effort in sorting the vector, look at this [survey paper of sorting algorithms](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.45.8017).

Answer (score 0):

Here is one basic example.

In a vector of $n$ numbers, you will be making $n-1$ comparisons.

E.g. $x_1 \le x_2$ then $x_2 \le x_3$ up to $x_{n-1} \le x_n$.

Define the indicator variable $I_i$ to be $1$ if $x_i \le x_{i+1}$ and $0$ otherwise.

Then you can rate a vector of length $n$ on a level of "orderedness" like so: $$O(\mathbf{v}) = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} I_i }{n-1}$$

In your two examples, this formula produces an "orderedness" value of $1$ and $0$ respectfully.